# Pandas DataFrame, How to obtain something like method .value_counts(), but its value as the index of that unique sequence of classes instead of count

Tags: python, pandas

Given my dataframe `df` has 11 rows and 5 classes, as the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(  [[0,0,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,1],
                    [0,0,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,1],
                    [0,0,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,1],
                    [0,0,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,1,0],
                    [0,1,1,0,0],
                    [1,0,0,1,0],
                    [0,1,1,0,0],
                    [1,0,0,1,0],
                    [0,1,1,0,1]])
```

Note that the columns of df are [0,1,2,3,4] as default
When you run `df.value_counts()`, you got

```
0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  0  0    4
      0  0  1    3
   1  1  0  0    2
1  0  0  1  0    2
0  0  0  1  0    1
   1  1  0  1    1
```

you could observe that it returns all unique sequence of 5 classes with its count (the sparse element represent zero, I guess), Now I am wondering **is there any possible way to get the index which contain each of these sequence of unique value in form of dictionary?**

so, for this case, it could return the following dictionary where its key represent each unique sequence of class and its value represent the list of index.. like this

```
{(0,0,1,0,0): [0,2,4,6],
 (0,0,0,0,1): [1,3,5],
 (0,1,1,0,0): [8,10,12],
 (1,0,0,1,0): [9,11],
 (0,0,0,1,0) :[7],
 (0,1,1,0,1): [1]}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply did `.groupby` method

So, `.groupby` which take the list of columns as input will group all possible combination of every columns, and we can follow `.groups` to access your expected dictionary

```
df.groupby([0,1,2,3,4]).groups
```

Result:

```
{(0, 0, 0, 0, 1): [1, 3, 5], (0, 0, 0, 1, 0): [7], (0, 0, 1, 0, 0): [0, 2, 4, 6], (0, 1, 1, 0, 0): [8, 10], (0, 1, 1, 0, 1): [12], (1, 0, 0, 1, 0): [9, 11]}
```